# How to dispatch an KeyboardEvent with specific KeyCode

Tags: events, keyboard, dart

I try to dispatch an keyboard event for the esc key (for testing)
this is what i got so far:

```dart
  KeyboardEvent keyEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keypress');

  window.onKeyPress.listen((KeyboardEvent event){
    KeyEvent keyEvent = new KeyEvent.wrap(event);
    if(keyEvent.keyCode == KeyCode.ESC){
      //do stuff
    }
  });

  window.dispatchEvent(keyEvent);
```

This works as expected. The onKeyPress listener triggers.

But i didn't find out how to set a KeyCode for my KeyBoardEvent?

Comment: Can't do that with `KeyboardEvent`.  Check out https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.KeyEvent for info on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the commet. I tried it like in the spec: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/f8d07191a5760be1e02b but it gives me the error: Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event is already being dispatched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't use `dispatchEvent`.  Try:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  Stream stream = KeyEvent.keyPressEvent.forTarget(document.body);
  stream.listen((KeyEvent keyEvent){
    if(keyEvent.keyCode == KeyCode.ESC) {
        // do stuff
    }
  });
  stream.add(new KeyEvent('keypress', keyCode: KeyCode.ESC));
}
```

as described in https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.KeyEvent