# how to simulate keystroke in browser

Tags: dart, keyevent, dart-html

Hi I cant seem to find the right way to simulate keyevents, I have come across 3 differend options I tried but none of them did work for me.

```
 //V1
 import 'dart:async';
 import 'dart:html';

 void main() {
     var stream = KeyEvent.keyPressEvent.forTarget(document.body);
     stream.listen((KeyEvent keyEvent){
         if(keyEvent.keyCode == KeyCode.ESC) {
        // do stuff
         }
     });
     stream.add(new KeyEvent('keypress', keyCode: KeyCode.ESC));
 }
```

-

```
 //V2
 import 'dart:html';

 myCustomKeyHandler(KeyEvent e) {
     print('The charCode is ${e.charCode}');
     print('The keyCode is ${e.keyCode}');
 }
 main() {
     var controller = new KeyboardEventController.keydown(document.window);
     controller.add(myCustomKeyHandler);
 }
```

-

```
 //V3
 import 'dart:html';
 myCustomKeyHandler(KeyboardEvent e) {
   print('The charCode is ${e.charCode}');
   print('The keyCode is ${e.keyCode}');
 }
 main() {
   document.window.add(myCustomKeyHandler, false);
 }
```

---

the best I get is

### Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event is already being dispatched.

sources
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/17950

[How to dispatch an KeyboardEvent with specific KeyCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058952/how-to-dispatch-an-keyboardevent-with-specific-keycode)

https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/mgnd1TUGn68